# regex in bash returns different results than ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, bash

I am trying to extract match groups from a string - I've used [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/OY3JfqbQQwinEH) to come up with a pattern:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Which in ruby, seems to extract the expected groups for the following string:

> 1547156981784 : Served [ Code128 ] with [ this_is_a_test ] in [ 12ms ] size [ 385B ] using [ http://barcodeapi.org/index.html ] for [ 1.2.3.4 ] via [ 5.6.7.8 ]

```
1: Code128
2: this_is_a_test
3: 12ms
4: 385B
5: http://barcodeapi.org/index.html
6: 1.2.3.4
7: 5.6.7.8
```

However this issue is that I am trying to implement this regex in a Bash script to parse a log file:

```
reg='\[(.*?)\]'
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $reg ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
  fi
done < $log
```

But the results are not the same as ruby / rubular; in Bash, match group #1 contains the whole string, minus the very first and very last brackets; for the same log line, bash returns only a single match:

```
1: Code128 ] with [ this_is_a_test ] in [ 12ms ] size [ 385B ] using [ http://barcodeapi.org/index.html ] for [ 1.2.3.4 ] via [ 5.6.7.8
```

Question being,

Why do the two engines give different results? How can I separate the groups properly using Bash?

Comment: `.*?` is non-greedy and part of PCRE, but not supported by Bash regular expressions, which are ERE only.

Comment: You should be able to use `\[([^]]*)\]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues:

1. There is no global match in Bash;
2. You need to manually loop over multiple matches in Bash and manually manage the string index;
3. There is no non greedy quantifier in ERE used in Bash regex, so `.*?` does not work the same as in Ruby.

You can use this as a start:

```
while read line; do
    while [[ $line =~ ([^\[]*)\[([^\]]*)\] ]]; do 
        i=${#BASH_REMATCH}
        line=${line:i}
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    done
done < file
```

Prints:

```
 Code128 
 this_is_a_test 
 12ms 
 385B 
 http://barcodeapi.org/index.html 
 1.2.3.4 
 5.6.7.8
```

And you will have *way* less headache if you just use Perl / GNU grep / Ruby / etc to create the list of matches and then use Bash to loop over *that*:

```
while read m; do
    echo "Match: $m"
done < <(ggrep -oP '(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])' file)  # GNU grep is ggrep here
```

If your code has to positively be POSIX, use `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' file
```